# Would a question about seemingly contradictory sources for voter fraud be on topic?

Tags: discussion

With all that's been made of President Trump's voter fraud panel in the news recently, I was looking around the internet when I stumbled upon two seemingly contradictory sources regarding cases of voter fraud.  One source states that there have been less than 100 cases of voter fraud, whereas another claims more than 1000.  Would this be appropriate for our site?

Comment: Can you specify your question? Is the claim about the number of cases claimed by the Trump election commission (ie one sources says they claim to have found 100 cases, while another says that they claim 1000 found cases)? That would certainly be on-topic. Whether those numbers are actually true might be off-topic as it is about a current investigation. Can you add your sources here? That would make it easier to determine if this is on-topic or not.

Comment: @tim Trump isn't actually one of my sources.  The New York Times is one of the sources, although there are plenty that claim the less than 100 number.  The 1000+ is the Heritage Foundation, in a big PDF available on their website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you can link to the two sources and they are notable (e.g. widely read).

[I am already suspicious that they have some sort of caveats or qualifiers, so they aren't talking about the same thing, but my mind is open - a direct contradiction between two sources is always more fun.]

Comment: I agree, I'm pretty sure the two sources are using two different definitions.  One is the New York Times and the other is the Heritage Foundation.  Thank you, I'm going to put the question together in a bit.